# When do we use the _ (underscore) for sql select query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I have come across one of the LIKE operators in sql which is the `_` (underscore)

I understand how it works as I have followed the tutorial from w3schools (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)

Question is, when is the suitable time to use it? - Regarding to web applications.

Comment: When you need to? This totally depends on your application and what it does.

Comment: You use it when there are single letter differences. For example `SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE "car_"` which would match `cart`, `cars`,... but wouldn't match `carton`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matches any single character.

The only time I ever use this in practice is when I want to find strings which contain a substring but don't end in that substring.

```
WHERE SomeCol LIKE '%foo_%'
```

ensures that at least one character follows "foo"

Comment: Thanks @Martin for your answer, I was wondering which bit in your application you used this? like some kind of search? query something before updating row?

Comment: @jonprasetyo - I usually use it for adhoc admin queries. Not sure I've ever used it in an application. The functionality is pretty dated and modern applications would likely use regular expressions for more sophisticated pattern matching and/or full text search for user search.